# Refer to a variable by pasting strings then make changes and see them refrelcted in the original variable

Tags: r

```
my_mtcars_1 <- mtcars
my_mtcars_2 <- mtcars
my_mtcars_3 <- mtcars

for(i in 1:3) {get(paste0('my_mtcars_', i))$blah <- 1}
Error in get(paste0("my_mtcars_", i))$blah <- 1 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I would like each of my 3 data frames to have a new field called blah that has a value of 1.

How can I iterate over a range of numbers in a loop and refer to DFs by name by pasting the variable name into a string and then edit the df in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three options all assume you want to modify them and keep them in the environment.

So, if it must be a dataframes (in your environment & in a loop) you could do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  obj_name = paste0('my_mtcars_', i)
  obj = get(obj_name)
  obj$blah = 1

  assign(obj_name, obj, envir = .GlobalEnv) # Send back to global environment
}
```

I agree with @Duck that a list is a better format (and preferred to the above loop). So, if you use a list and need it in your environment, use what Duck suggested with `list2env()` and send everything back to the `.GlobalEnv`. I.e. (in one ugly line),

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "my_mtcars_")), function(x) {x[["blah"]] = 1; x}), .GlobalEnv)
```

Or, if you are amenable to working with `data.table`, you could use the `set()` function to add columns:

```
library(data.table)

# assuming my_mtcars_* is already a data.table
for(i in 1:3) {
  set(get(paste0('my_mtcars_', i)), NULL, "blah", 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggestion, it is better if you manage data inside a list and use `lapply()` instead of loop:

```
#List
List <- list(my_mtcars_1 = mtcars,
             my_mtcars_2 = mtcars,
             my_mtcars_3 = mtcars)
#Variable
List2 <- lapply(List,function(x) {x$bla <- 1;return(x)})
```

And it is easy to store your data using a code like this:

```
#List
List <- mget(ls(pattern = 'my_mt'))
```

So no need of defining each dataset individually.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(mget(ls(pattern = '^my_mtcars_\\d+$')), ~ .x %>%
                mutate(blah = 1)) %>%
      list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```